# If string contains forward slash

Tags: php, string, if-statement

How do i make a if statement which checks if the string contains a forward slash?

```
$string = "Test/Test";   
if($string .......)
{
    mysql_query(""); 
} 
else 
{
    echo "the value contains a invalid character"; 
}
```

Comment: [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php): `if (strpos($string, '/') !== FALSE) { echo "It contains a /"; }`

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->contains('/')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L93) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use strpos, which will make sure there is a forward slash in the string but you need to run it through an equation to make sure it's not false. Here you can use [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php). Its short and simple code, and gets the job done!

```
if(strstr($string, '/')){
    //....
}
```

For those who live and die by the manual, when the haystack is very large, or the needle is very small, it is quicker to use `strstr()`, despite what the manual says.

Example:

Using `strpos()`: 0.00043487548828125

Using `strstr()`: 0.00023317337036133

Comment: [`If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Comment: I submitted an edit to the manual, because that note only applies to large haystacks.

Answer (score 8):

```
if(strpos($string, '/') !== false) {
  // string contains /
}
```

From the PHP manual of [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

> Note:
>
> If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within
>   haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos()
>   instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

If it doesn't return false, the character was matched.

Answer (score 0):

I compared strpos() results with 0. Somehow comparison with false did not work for me.

```
if (strpos($t, '/') !== 0) {
  echo "No forward slash!";
}
```